# python regex to find php functions in files

Tags: php, python, regex

I’m looking for a regular expression to match all functions blocks (from start to end) in php files. For example:

```
function test_function($var) {
 if ($var == 'somethin') {
 print 'hi';
 }
 etc.
}
```

I need the start offset and end offset of the block. What regex can I use?

Comment: Regular expressions are not exactly a good choice for this. You'd be better off with a simple parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very very complicated and can't be done with one regular expression.

You may think that you can easily match `the beginning of a function like this:

```
\bfunction\b\s+\S+[^\(](\s+)?\(.*?\)\s+\{
```

But you can't because what is if there is this in a code?

```
$string = "function myfunction() {}";
```

So you should search on everything what isn't quoted. So for excluding quoted strings you can use this regular expression:

```
(?:(?=(?:(?:\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|[^\\'"])*'(?:\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"'\\])*"|[^\\'])*')*(?:\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*"|[^\\'])*$)(?=(?:(?:\\.|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|[^\\'"])*"(?:\\.|'(?:\\.|[^'"\\])*'|[^\\"])*")*(?:\\.|'(?:\\.|[^'\\])*'|[^\\"])*$)(?:\\.|[^\\'"]))+
```

The next thing you should do is counting all `{` and `}` because you need to know when the function stops and I can't think about any regular expression which can do this. So you need to do this with looping through.

Comment: You can do the `{` counting with `(?R` (well, probably not in Python), and some subroutines would simplify the quotes thing. For arbitrary PHP it would also need to watch out for comments, etc. But this looks like a good partial solution. (Approximations are often the better option.)

Comment: @micha, what is that *excluding quoted strings* regex supposed to do exactly? And it seem it will not work properly with PHP strings, as it does not treat `'foo"bar'` as a valid string.

Comment: It will select everything except quoted strings. See it in [action](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2vcr2)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this: https://github.com/ramen/phply

Comment: Interesting, altho it currently doesn't support several quoting constructs.

Comment: It's pretty cool that someone went all that way. "Learning more about parsing "industrial" languages, *warts and all*". haha